# How to display the query results from parse.com in table format using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, parse-platform

```
     /*student.html*/
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html ng-app="">
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src= "students.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
  <div class="container" ng-controller="userController">

  <h3>Students</h3>

   <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead><tr>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>
  <button class="btn" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit
  </button>
</td>
<td>{{ user.firstname}}</td>
<td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
<td>{{ user.age }}</td>
   </tr></tbody>
 </table>

<hr>
 </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Please help me I am a newbie to angularjs and also using parse for first time.I got stuck at displaying query results(which is an array of objects) using ng-repeat in angularjs..anyone who had come across the same issue,please contribute your answer..

```
/*stduents.js*/
function userController($scope) {
var users=[];
Parse.initialize("parseid", "jskey");//parseid and jskey are given in my parse.com account
var student=Parse.Object.extend("student");//student is a class in parse.com
var query=new Parse.Query(student);
query.equalTo("userid",Parse.User.current());
query.find({
success:function(results) {
alert("success");
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
{
 var object= results[i];
users.push({'firstname':object.get('firstname') , 'lastname':object.get('lastname') ,'age':object.get('age')});

}

},
 error:function(error) {
 alert("error:"+ error.code +" "+error.message);
 }
});
```

Comment: Please add enough code and markup snippets to demonstrate the approach you attempted which is currently failing.

Comment: hi @mccainz I have added code snippets .please check it out .

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/sogtgtDrz21pd9p2yXhj?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Simple usage of `ng-repeat`:

*Sample array*

```
var arr = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
]
```

*Sample usage*

```
<span ng-repeat="obj in arr">{{obj.id}}</span>
```

This will give you

```
123
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11389/)

I suggest reading the [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: Yes I know the above one, but the array returned by parse.com query result is different (it returns array of objects "not a simple array which you have taken")..

Comment: my question is how to change "users" array(in my code) into the format of simple array "arr"(in your code)??

Comment: give us a sample of your *JSON*

Comment: var users=[{firstname:'sharath' ,lastname:'reddy' ,age:22}];

Comment: and what should it look like?

Comment: sorry i dont have enough credits to add pic of output

Comment: just send me sample code how to retrieve objects from parse.com for a query and print it on screen using angularjs (ng-repeat)

Comment: You have had several problems in your plunkr: 1. no jQuery, 2. the line `query.equalTo("uname",$scope.use.get('username'));`, 3. you need to call `$scope.$apply();` after pushing the result objects into your scope array. But this is working now: http://plnkr.co/edit/iMcik7MXHXielYTmgB1B?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

just correct third line in students.js to $scope.users=[];

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: hi @callmekatootie ,actually the author is my friend ,i saw his code and i found the mistake,according to his code,the above specified answer made  his code work